# cannot connect to access database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to connect to my access database which is mdb to vb.net project. I've changed the platform to x86 but it's still not working. I can't really seem to know what the problem is.  Hope I can get some help, thank you in advance

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb 'provides classes to connect to the database

Public Class Form1
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID as [No], " & _
                                   "UserName as [Name], " & _
                                   "FROM Table1 " & _
                                   "ORDER BY ID", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data to dataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    'Offer data in dataTable to dataGridView
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    'close connection
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn = New OleDbConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OleDB.4.0; Data Source= C:\Users\user\Documents\Access Database\Database2.mdb"

    RefreshData()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message, but the data is not showing in the data grid view @Jeroen

Comment: Given that you're calling that `RefreshData` method in the `Load` event handler, there could be an exception being thrown but it would be swallowed silently. Wrap the call in a `Try...Catch` block to find out.  If there is an exception then either you or us can work out the issue from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your SQL statement. The code:

```
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID as [No], " & _
    "UserName as [Name], " & _
    "FROM Table1 " & _
    "ORDER BY ID", conn)
```

Should **NOT** have a comma after `as [Name],`
Instead it should read:

```
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID as [No], " & _
    "UserName as [Name] " & _ `NO COMMA!
    "FROM Table1 " & _
    "ORDER BY ID", conn)
```

Comment: I don't know how you got your version to compile. Visual Studio told me where the error was straight away...